# How to install "Cycles Minecraft Rig BSS" (Blender 2.9x)?

Tags: add-on, installation

We are trying to install Rymdnisse ([Cycles_Minecraft_Rig BSS Edit V6.5.zip](https://nilssoderman.com/downloads/minecraft-blender-rig/)) add-on for Blender 2.9. We go to *Edit > Preferences > Add-Ons*, and install from MacBook Downloads folder.

It says it installs, but we cannot locate the add-on in the Community, Official or Testing lists to select it to make it active.

Comment: The link you sent was about a Minecraft rigs collection. Rigs are not add-ons. If fact,rigs are very different from add-ons and cannot be installed but imported into the scene

Answer (score 0):

It's a rig, not an addon. You need to append it into the scene.